# How to create a rating post?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a list of lessons and next to each lesson will be the `input type = "radio"` to evaluate that lesson from 1 to 10 points. I want to click on the radio button will get the value of that button and save the value to the database. But it doesn't seem to work.

```php
<tbody>
   @foreach($rates as $rate)
   <form method="post" action="{{url('/rating')}}">
   <input type="hidden" name="rateId" value="{{$rate->id}}">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
        <tr style="display: flex;">
          <td class="col-md-1"></td>
          <td class="col-md-6" style="text-align: left;"><a href="{{url('/bai-giang/'.$rate->id)}}">{{$rate->title}}</a></td>
          <td class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center;"></td>
          <td class="col-md-2">
          <div align="center" style="display: inline-flex;">
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" onclick="return confirmAction()">
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" onclick="return confirmAction()">
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" onclick="return confirmAction()">
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" onclick="return confirmAction()">
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" onclick="return confirmAction()">
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="6" onclick="return confirmAction()">
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="7" onclick="return confirmAction()">
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="8" onclick="return confirmAction()">
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="9" onclick="return confirmAction()">
         <input type="radio" name="rating" value="10" onclick="return confirmAction()">
          </div>
       </td>
  </tr>
</form>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

My function to save value form radio button

```php
    public function rating(Request $req)
        {
            $id = $req->rateId;
            $lesson = Lesson::find($id);
            $lesson->rating = $req->rating;
            $lesson->save();
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Rating successful');
        }
```

Comment: "_But it doesn't seem to work_" What does that mean? Is the wrong article rated? Do you get wrong ratings? Can you please also post the Javascript behind it?

Comment: That javascript simply shows a yes / no message

Comment: post also your controller and what you have tried

Comment: you must use a button to submit the form or use ajax javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio for radio buttons and naming them. Also, `<form>` inside `<tbody>` is not valid, place your form inside a `<td>`

Comment: @Steven it's updated

Comment: @MahdiClash I just wanted to do it simply using html and php like this

Comment: @TrucPham I think you can't do that you must use ajax or form submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` property in the `input` tag should be the same for all radio buttons and you should use that name while getting the selected value.

Example:

```
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" onclick="return confirmAction()">
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" onclick="return confirmAction()">
```